# integrating leaderboard from Newgrounds in flash game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, leaderboards, scoring

I have made flash game and I want to show a leader board in that game.
I have uploaded my game to kongregate.com.

I have made a scoreboard there with the name of **overLoadScore** (overload is the name of my game). 
i dragged an instance of API Loader component.

in my Main.as file I have the code.

```
var scoreBoard:ScoreBoard = new SoreBoard();
scoreBrowser.scoreBoardName = "overLoadScore";
scoreBrowser.loadScores();
scoreBoard.period = ScoreBoard.ALL_TIME;
```

i am getting the error
    call to a possibly undefined method ALL_TIME with reference to static type class ScoreBoard.

although i have provided correct API ID and encryption key.But in the output window i am getting the message.
**[Newgrounds API] :: No API ID entered in the API Connector component.**

and i have created the scoreBoard which i mentioned earlier but what is this

**[Newgrounds API] :: No scoreboards created for this movie.**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing code for you.

Comment: If you simply want example code, well there's already example code in kongregate's documentation. A question that would be on-topic is if you actually tried to implement their code and encountered a specific problem.

Comment: @jhocking i have edited the question please can u help

Comment: Wait, at first you mention Kongregate, then you say Newgrounds. What platform are you targeting now? What does their documentation say?

Comment: @Anko sorry my mistake it is Newgrounds. i am targetting newgrounds and i am following their doccumentation but cant get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the line 1 with

```
var scoreBrowser:ScoreBrowser = new ScoreBrowser();
```

actually i mingled **scoreBrowser** and **scoreBoard**.